# How to dynamically import multiple Vue components under the same chunk name?

Tags: webpack, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, code-splitting

I am trying to import multiple Vue components as a chunk and I would preferably only use the `magic comment` to assign the chunkname once.

This is what I have tried:

`import(/* webpackChunkName: 'googlemap' */ '@/components/maps');`

And the file that I am importing:

```
import Vue from 'vue';

Vue.component('google-map', () => import('@/components/maps/GoogleMapAsync.vue'));
Vue.component('widget', () => import('@/components/maps/widgets/WidgetAsync.vue'));
Vue.component('price-widget', () => import('@/components/maps/widgets/PriceWidgetAsync.vue'));
Vue.component('map-marker', () => import('@/components/maps/marker/MapMarkerAsync.vue'));
Vue.component('map-price-marker', () => import('@/components/maps/marker/MapPriceMarkerAsync.vue'));
```

This does not create the the proper chunk with the name of `googlemap`. Previously I had simply put the `webpackChunkName` in front of each import, but I would like to simply only have to assign the `webpackChunkName` once since these components will only be grouped anyways.

What I am trying to do is essential the same as this:

https://hackernoon.com/effective-code-splitting-in-react-a-practical-guide-2195359d5d49#697a

Is there another way to get this working?

Comment: Having a similar problem, any joy figuring this out?

Comment: Not really. I have resorted to importing them one by one and setting the proper `webpackChunkName` for each one. It does not seems to work properly at the moment but I have not invested much time into figuring this out.

Comment: Perhaps webpack 4, https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/issues/1280. Noted one comment has named chunks.

Comment: I think you have to use [double quotes](https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/blob/master/docs/rules/dynamic-import-chunkname.md) for the chunk name. Following the official guide at https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/ and adjustments on my webpack config I use code splitting with named chunks  successfully.

Answer (score 2):

I use the following that uses each file name as the component name and I prefix it with vue-

```
const files = require.context('./', true, /\.vue$/i)
files.keys().map(key => Vue.component('Vue' + key.split('/').pop().split('.')[0], files(key).default))
```

That will give you what you want. You can remove the prefix if you like however if you ever have an element that exists in HTML or an element ever gets created I prefer to have it.

Comment: This is not using, dynamic imports as OP is requesting. Alternatively you could use  require.context with a fourth string paramater with value as: 'lazy', then remove the ".default" part of "files(key)".